# Java. Cant parse date using DateFormat

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have a date string:

```
Thu Feb 20 08:00:00 EET 1992
```

And using this code to format it:

```
String datePatternFrom = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy";
String datePatternTo = "MMM dd, yyyy";
String prettyDate = "";

try {
    DateFormat fromFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternFrom);
    Date date = (Date)fromFormatter.parse(userBirthday.toString());

    DateFormat toFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternTo);
    prettyDate = toFormatter.format(date);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why I'am getting the exception?

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Feb 20 08:00:00 EET 1992" (at offset 0)
```

Comment: No exception on my pc. What java version you use? 32 bit, 64 bit?

Comment: userBirthday is Date object. When I convert it toString() I have date as I mentioned..

Comment: why not just use `prettyDate = toFormatter.format(userBirthday);` if `userBirthday` is `Date` already?

Comment: Vladimir format function param must be string...

Comment: it's `Date` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date) . Even your `date` is of `Date` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the weekday and month and your locale.
`Thu` is English, so you have to tell the parser that it should use English weekdays:

```
DateFormat fromFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePatternFrom, Locale.US);
```

This will work for your pattern.
If you do not specify a locale, the default will be used, which is not always an English one. ;-)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Can @user1766287 please verify it?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for delay :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your userBirthday object was not created as a java.util.Date object. Can you try a `System.out.println(userBirthday.getClass().getName());`?

Comment: why? there is a day of week at the beginning of the string. or did you mean they should try it on a substring?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your locale. Try making a SDF with datePatternFrom, give it a date to *format* and print that somewhere. See what pops up.